# Elasticsearch and Asp.Net Core

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nest

I'm planning to build a simple forum and I've choose to do it with the new Asp.Net Core. I will use Elasticsearch and Nest library for searching inside it.

I wonder if Nest.Net version 2.4.6 is supported for Asp.Net Core? Where I can check that before start to writing code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [it does!](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2138).

We currently support .NETStandard1.3 and greater, and are hoping we can drop down to [1.1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2157), but there are a few dependencies blocking us at the moment.